# Can I add combo box and radio box in to popup window?

Tags: java, swing, popup, jcombobox, joptionpane

I want to a popup Window to which I can add  radio boxes and combo box. According to their data program will go on `JFrame`. I tried to add option pane. However need to add radio boxes and combo box on the option pane.

How can I do it? Can option pane be used for this purpose? What is your suggestion in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. You should also know how to properly provide a [mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable) example.

Comment: @Nytrix Great suggestion, and a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment automatically expands to [mcve].

Comment: @AndrewThompson we learn everyday, thankyou!

Comment: @Nytrix *"we learn everyday"* Too true. A day with nothing learned, is a day wasted.

Answer (score 1):

The JOptionPane has limited customisation options. Go with `JDialog` - [here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#dialogdemo) the Oracle's demo for it.

Comment: You can add any component to a JOptionPane. This means you can add a JPanel containing any number of components.

Comment: @camickr Really? I'm all in to learn something new. A pointer to a constructor or method which allows me to create a JOptionPane with my custom component, please?

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617390/how-to-set-manage-the-layout-of-joptionpane/17617861#17617861

Comment: @camickr Thanks, indeed. Sometimes it pays to read the upper side of the Javadoc page - this is one of the cases.

Comment: @camickr  Only a bit longer and perhaps I'll get some time to edit the answer.