# class variable not updating after method call

Tags: java, swing, interface, radio-button

I am quite new to Java and only after researching and googling and reading many answers, I am posting this. I am kinda lost. A little guidance would be of great help. The following is a method from a class that implements the "ActionListener" interface. What I am trying to do is this: There is a button which one clicked should open a new window with two options in the form of two Radio Buttons. I need to know the Radio Button which was selected for further use in my code. I declared, the "scoreOption" variable as a class variable and static, and then attempt to update it in the "actionPerformed" abstract method. But when I refer to it (after the method call), the value stays the same - null, or whatever I set it to initially. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class StartEvents implements ActionListener {
    StartPanel startingPanel;
    static String scoreOption;
    
    public StartEvents(StartPanel startPanel) {
        startingPanel = startPanel;
    }
    // Scoring System Window - 1
    public void scoringSystem() {
        startingPanel.scoringSystem.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Panel scoringSystemPanel = new Panel();
                JFrame scoreSystemFrame  = scoringSystemPanel.frame(150, 250, "Scoring System", 2, true);
                JPanel scoreSystemPanel = scoringSystemPanel.panel(Color.lightGray);
                JButton confirmSelection = scoringSystemPanel.button(40, 20, "Confirm");
                JRadioButton scoreSystem1 = scoringSystemPanel.radioButton("Option 1: Same Points Per Hit");    
                scoreSystem1.setActionCommand("Option 1");
                JRadioButton scoreSystem2 = scoringSystemPanel.radioButton("Option 2: Unique Points Per Hit");
                scoreSystem2.setActionCommand("Option 2");
                ButtonGroup scoreSys = new ButtonGroup();
                scoreSys.add(scoreSystem1);
                scoreSys.add(scoreSystem2);
                scoreSystemFrame.getContentPane().add(scoreSystemPanel);
                scoreSystemPanel.add(scoreSystem1);
                scoreSystemPanel.add(scoreSystem2);
                scoreSystemPanel.add(confirmSelection);
                
                // Get Selection Event
                // Option 1
                scoreSystem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (scoreSystem1.isSelected()) {
                            scoreOption = scoreSystem1.getActionCommand();
                        }
                    }
                });
                // Option 2
                scoreSystem2.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (scoreSystem2.isSelected()) {
                            scoreOption = scoreSystem2.getActionCommand();
                        }
                    }
                });
                // Confirm Event 
                confirmSelection.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        scoreSystemFrame.dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Main Game Class where the method scoringsystem is called.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartPanel startingPanel = new StartPanel();
        startingPanel.makeStartPanel();
        StartEvents starter = new StartEvents(startingPanel);
        starter.rulesButton();
        starter.exitButton();
        starter.highScoresButton();
        ArrayList<Integer> dimensions = starter.boardSizeSelector();
        
        // Problem Zone
        System.out.println(StartEvents.scoreOption);
        starter.scoringSystem();
        System.out.println(StartEvents.scoreOption);
        // The two values of scoreOption should be different
        
        String[] playPanelDetails = {"970", "Player 1", "450"};
        
        // Final Start of the Game
        starter.startGameButton(playPanelDetails, dimensions);
        
    }

}
```

Furthermore, could you please let me know regarding the following questions:

1. Implementing "ActionListener" within another "ActionListener" is recommended? Good Practice?
2. Can there only be one declaration of the "actionPerformed" method or can it be overloaded too?
3. Is it possible to get a return value from "actionPerformed" method?

I would be really grateful if even some hints could be provided. I really tried a lot and only then posting it here. Thank you very much in advance.

Small Edit: When I "System.out.println" the "actioncommand" there itself, it does work perfectly, printing in the console. But not when I try to update the class variable and then try to print it after the method call. Dunno if this helps.

Comment: Look up the [mre] link because this would be the best way for others to know why this current code is not working as expected. The link will explain what this is, how to create one, and why it can help you and us. Note that it is not a request for your entire program or un-runnable snippets (like your providing now) but a new small demo program that we can run and that shows us the problem.

Comment: To my eyes, we cannot see from the code above why scoreOption remains null, other than a JFrame is not a modal window, and you certainly don't want to display multiple JFrames in your application. Perhaps you need a modal dialog window such as a modal JDialog rather than a JFrame. There are other reasons for the variable being null, such as variable shadowing, but again whether this is happening is anyone's guess.

Comment: Can you at least show us the declaration of `scoreOption`?

Comment: Regarding ActionListener within ActionListener, in general, this is OK, but really this code should be greatly re-factored into different classes, much less different methods.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I added the complete class. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Does your `scoringSystem` method get called anywhere?

Comment: Uggg, static field -- bad code smell. And yes, I'm still wondering if the lack of window modality is the problem. But still no [mre] -- did you get a chance to check the link I've given you? And why are you not replying to me yet?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Please check the Edit. I added the class which calls it

Comment: YES. I was right! your problem is due to lack of modality. Again, why are you not addressing this issue or my comments??

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am reading through it already. Trying to maybe refactor the code in a way so that you can try it out. Working on it. There are many classes etc. Let me see please. And about static, I read another post where it was mentioned and recommended that such variables should be static, then only I did.

Comment: But your actionPerformed method isn't updating anything.  It's only setting things up so that you've got some buttons that do the updating.  Unless you can click those buttons in between your two calls to `System.out.println(StartEvents.scoreOption)`, nothing's going to change.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I see, however as I mentioned above, when I try to print stuff (actionCommand), it works but not when i call the method. I too had this thought that I am not doing anything - how could I rectify it? Any hints?

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to rectify.  It's perfectly correct that those two `System.out.println` lines should print exactly the same thing.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Ok, then let me rephrase it - I need to know the selected radio button/option as I wrote above, it is my final goal on the basis of which i would take further action. Then how can I obtain/get the selected radio button in return. I am sure - that which radio button is selected part is correct, but how to get it from the scoringSystem method?

Comment: You can't get it from the scoringSystem method, because all the scoringSystem method does is just set up the mechanism for recording which button gets selected.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I am going through your answer and the other one also posted by Camickr. Need some minutes to digest what you posted :P

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you so very much. I believe I understand now. Learnt something new about Modality, had not clue. Appreciate the super fast help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFrames are not modal -- you create one and display it, it does not block the code flow, and so you are extracting the value of scoreOption right as the JFrame is being displayed and ***before*** the user has had any chance to change it. You need to use a modal dialog such as a JDialog that is created as a modal dialog or use a JOptionPane (which is actually just a modal JDialog under the hood). This will block the flow of code so that you extract the data only after it has been changed by the user.

An example that proves the point:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FooGui01 extends JPanel {
    private String frameTest = "";
    private String dialogTest = "";
    private JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main GUI");
    
    private JFrame subFrame;
    private JDialog dialog;

    
    public FooGui01() {
        JButton showFrameBtn = new JButton("Show JFrame");
        showFrameBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            changeTest1WithJFrame();
            System.out.println("frameTest: " + frameTest);
        });
        
        JButton showDialogBtn = new JButton("Show JDialog");
        showDialogBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            changeTest2WithModalDialog();
            System.out.println("dialogTest: " + dialogTest);
        });
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(showDialogBtn);
        panel.add(showFrameBtn);
        
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.add(panel);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public void changeTest1WithJFrame() {

        if (subFrame == null) {
            subFrame = new JFrame("Frame");
            JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                frameTest = "Hello World and frameTest";
                subFrame.setVisible(false);
            });

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(button);
            
            subFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            subFrame.add(panel);
            subFrame.pack();
            subFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        }
        subFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void changeTest2WithModalDialog() {
        
        if (dialog == null) {       
            dialog = new JDialog(mainFrame, "Dialog", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                dialogTest = "Hello World and dialogTest";
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            });

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(button);
            
            dialog.add(panel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        }
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new FooGui01());
    }
}
```

If you run the code, when you show the sub JFrame, the test text is displayed immediately in the console *before* the dialog has been dealt with. If you press the button to show the dialog, the test text display is delayed until after the button has been pushed, changing the text.

Pressing the frame button twice will finally show the correct text since the text was set by the first time it was displayed.

Comment: Could you please explain "modal" in this context in a more descriptive way. I believe I can see where I went wrong, still you being pro could give me a little more insight for sure :)

Comment: @fattypanda hang on

Comment: small update - It still doesn't work with JDialog. I just tried it. Same issue. I believe the problem is somewhere else or?

Comment: Nope, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

A JDialig is just like a JFrame. That is you add components to it like you do any frame.

The difference is that you can make a JDialog modal. This means that when you use:

```
dialog.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("here");
```

The code after the setVisible(...) statement will not be executed until the dialog is closed. It also means you can't click on the parent JFrame until the dialog is closed.

An easy way to create a `modal JDialog` is to use a `JOptionPane`. It has some predefined methods that make prompting for user input easy.

For example in your case you could do something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    private int scoringOption = -1;

    public SSCCE()
    {
        JButton button = new JButton("Change Points Option");
        add(button);

        button.addActionListener((e) -> displayOptionDialog());
    }

    private void displayOptionDialog()
    {
        Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( this );

        // Custom button text

        Object[] options = {"Option 1: Same Points Per Hit", "Option 2: Unique Points Per Hit"};

        scoringOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            window,
            "Select your scoring option:",
            "Scoring Option",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            null);

        System.out.println( scoringOption );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

The above is also an example of an "MRE". The code is simple and contained in a single class that you can copy/paste/compile and test.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more examples of using a `JOptionPane`.

If you really want to use radio buttons, then you can create a panel with the radio buttons and display them on the option pane using the `showConfirmDialog(...)` method. When the dialog closes you would then need to get the action command from the `ButtonModel` of the `ButtonGroup`.

See: [how to set & manage the layout of JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617390/how-to-set-manage-the-layout-of-joptionpane/17617861#17617861) for a basic example of this approach to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the code and for the last comments - will try that too once :)