# How to define the JOptionPane showMessageDialog multiple lines; JRadioButton and JList together?

Tags: java

Now, I know only use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog with Text to fill blank box like this below.

```
enter code here         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null,"\n                         Desciption" +
            "\n ID: " + txtAP_ID.getText() +
            "\n Fullname: " + txtAP_NAME.getText() +
            "\n Address: "+ txtAP_ADDRESS.getText());
```

But, I want to show multiple lines in frame that use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog code with the JRadioButton and JList that were the choices, I want to write the code next to that code above. How can I do?

Comment: `JOptionPane` is for simple dialogue boxes. If you want a more complex setup with radio buttons and list boxes, you need to make a window yourself.

Comment: You can add a `JPanel` to a `JOptionPane`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617390/how-to-set-manage-the-layout-of-joptionpane/17617861#17617861 for a basic example. For full control over components use a modal JDialog.