# How to add an Image to a JOptionPane.showInputDialog()?

Tags: java, user-interface

[image: I want to add an image I have in the place of the question mark]

How do I do it? I tried to do it via a Label and it won't add it. And I think there is an easier way to do it than doing a JLabel.

Here's the code for this bit:

```java
    public void popUpUserEntry(){
     firstnameInput = new JFrame(); //It has been declared as an instance
     ImageIcon p1Image = new ImageIcon("p1.png");
     JLabel p1ImageLabel = new JLabel();
     p1ImageLabel.add(p1Image);
     String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(firstnameInput, "Enter 1st Player's 
     name: ");
     p1Name = (firstName); //Instance that stores first player's name
     firstnameInput.dispose();
     }
```

Comment: Try setting the icon with [this ctor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Object,int,int,javax.swing.Icon))

Comment: Try `p1ImageLabel.setIcon(p1Image);`

Comment: I think in my suggestion and that of @majusebetter you need the reference to the *instance* of the option pane

Comment: Generally, it’s not enough to create something, you also have to *use* it. The `JOptionPane` doesn’t know that you have created a label. Then, get used to consulting the documentation. There is [a `showInputDialog` variant accepting an `Icon`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int,javax.swing.Icon,java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object))

Comment: Is using JTextField a better a option and an easier one to do with that kind of stuff?

Comment: Add an image where? To replace the "?" icon? To the OK button? To the text field? Beside the existing "Enter player name" label? Be specific when asking a question. Maybe you want a little more control over the components visible in the option pane? Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617390/how-to-set-manage-the-layout-of-joptionpane/17617861#17617861 for an example that allows you to provide your own custom panel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method available which takes icon as an input, you can try it.
link:

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: Is using JTextField a better a option and an easier one to do with that kind of stuff?